# How to remove a bot integration from Slack?

Tags: slack, bot

I want to completely remove a bot I created on Slack. I can disable it but not completely remove it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to https://yourteamname.slack.com/apps/manage
2. Select the bot which you want to remove
3. Select revoke permissions and authorizations to this app
4. Select Remove the bot

Answer (score 5):

Slack gave me an answer via Twitter:

> Slack API ‏@SlackAPI Jul 14
>
> Currently not possible, unfortunately. But we are working changes that
>   will allow it. Stay tuned!

Comment: Any new developments? Has this feature been added in the last 17 months?

Answer (score 3):

I have removed applications from the page `https://[yourteamname].slack.com/apps/manage`.

Change [yourteamname] to your team name.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Though you cannot take any action on the bots in the my.slack.com/admin page, I was able to go to the "apps" section and all of my bots showed up there. Then I clicked on the bot I wanted to remove and hit "remove app" at the bottom of my screen. Not the greatest implementation but at least it appears there is a solution!

I am also the team owner, so you likely need to be that to remove a bot